# Has the philosophy of technology's impact on human life so far been studied?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-technology

There is no doubt that technology has influenced human life، Has the impact of technology on human life been examined from a philosophical point of view? 
(Particularly the impact of technological evolution on human lifestyle)
For example, the widespread use of smartphones.

Comment: See [Baudrillard on SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/baudrillard/#2) "*Henceforth, signs and codes proliferate and produce other signs and new sign machines in ever-expanding and spiraling cycles. Technology thus replaces capital in this story and semiurgy (interpreted by Baudrillard as proliferation of images, information, and signs) replaces production.*" His [Simulacra and Simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacra_and_Simulation) inspired the Matrix.

Comment: Here are some books/articles from Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/HansJonasTowardAPhilosophyOfTechnology ; https://archive.org/details/ThinkingThroughTechnologyThePathBetweenEngineeringAndPhilosophy ; || and a real book https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Philosophy+of+Technology%3A+The+Technological+Condition%3A+An+Anthology%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118547250 maybe you have read some of this already.

Comment: "Many students who come into my AP Calculus class place far too much faith in calculator results, blindly accepting results without questioning whether they’re correct or even reasonable. " by Mark Howell, Gonzaga College High School.  I like this guy. What happened to the sliderule?  I note you are an engineer and there are already warnings about blindly accepting digital results, but there is some loss of felt Reason with the loss of the analog.

Comment: https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/courses/resources/examples-of-calculator-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heidegger was much concerned with this. A central text is : 'The Question Concerning Technology and Other Essays, ed., trans., William Lovitt (New York: Harper & Row, 1977).

David Edward Tabachnick has a useful article: 'Heidegger's Essentialist Responses to the Challenge of Technology', Canadian Journal of Political Science / Revue canadienne de science politique, Vol. 40, No. 2 (Jun., 2007), pp. 487-505: 492:

> Heidegger called for the defiant recapturing of a pre-technological world
>    through the destruction of the scientific establishment that he under
>    stood to be an obstacle to "authentic being." He comes to the astonishing conclusion that:
>
> > From a metaphysical point of view, Russia and America are the same; the same
> >      dreary technological frenzy, the same unrestricted organization of the average
> >      man ... The spiritual decline of the earth is so far advanced that the nations are
> >      in danger of losing the last bit of spiritual energy that makes it possible to see
> >      the decline (taken in relation to the history of "being"), and to appraise it as
> >      such. (Heidegger, An Introduction to Metaphysics. Trans. Ralph Manheim. New
> >      Haven: Yale University Press: 37-8.

This gives only a sample dip into Heidegger's critique of technology but it may be a useful pointer.